# traversing array for comparing two indexes for duplicates

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that looks like this:

```
[special_days_nested_array] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [day_name] => Mon
                    [start_time] => 01:00 pm
                    [end_time] => 07:00 pm
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [day_name] => Wed
                    [start_time] => 01:00 pm
                    [end_time] => 07:00 pm
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [day_name] => Fri
                    [start_time] => 01:00 pm
                    [end_time] => 07:00 pm
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [day_name] => Sun
                    [start_time] => 01:00 pm
                    [end_time] => 07:00 pm
                )

        )
```

Case 1:
When I traverse over this array to find duplicates -- where two timings are same. 
For example, Here all the times are same for these days, I should get the arrays where I store days as this:

```
[special_days_same_time_array] => Array
        (
            [0] => Mon
            [1] => Wed
            [2] => Fri
            [3] => Sun
        )
```

But, instead, I get something like this:

```
[special_days_same_time_array] => Array
        (
            [0] => Mon
            [1] => Wed
            [2] => Wed
            [3] => Fri
            [4] => Fri
            [5] => Sun
        )
```

Case 2:
When my nested array looks like this:

```
[special_days_nested_array] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [day_name] => Mon
                    [start_time] => 01:00 pm
                    [end_time] => 07:00 pm
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [day_name] => Tue
                    [start_time] => 12:00 am
                    [end_time] => 09:00 pm
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [day_name] => Wed
                    [start_time] => 01:00 pm
                    [end_time] => 07:00 pm
                )

        )
```

That is the same time are not in consecutive days, but the alternate days, my array remains empty (or there is no array at all)
Case 3: 
When two days have same time, and other two days have same time, something like this:

```
[special_days_nested_array] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [day_name] => Mon
                    [start_time] => 01:00 pm
                    [end_time] => 07:00 pm
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [day_name] => Tue
                    [start_time] => 01:00 pm
                    [end_time] => 07:00 pm
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [day_name] => Wed
                    [start_time] => 12:00 am
                    [end_time] => 09:00 pm
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [day_name] => Thu
                    [start_time] => 12:00 am
                    [end_time] => 09:00 pm
                )

        )
```

I only get one time in this:

```
[special_timings_same_time] => 12:00 am - 09:00 pm
```

And also, the same days array is like this:

```
[special_days_same_time_array] => Array
        (
            [0] => Mon
            [1] => Tue
            [2] => Wed
            [3] => Thu
        )
```

All these days get timings as 12:00 am - 9:00 pm

This is my code, where I trying to sort between same times and different times array.

```
//Special timings to check for the same time of two days
        //$j = 0;
        for($j = 0; $j < count($data_set->special_days_nested_array)-1; $j++){

            if(($data_set->special_days_nested_array[$j]['start_time'] == $data_set->special_days_nested_array[$j+1]['start_time']) && ($data_set->special_days_nested_array[$j]['end_time'] == $data_set->special_days_nested_array[$j+1]['end_time']) ) {
                    //Days Array
                    $data_set->special_days_same_time_array[] = $data_set->special_days_nested_array[$j]['day_name'];
                    $data_set->special_days_same_time_array[] = $data_set->special_days_nested_array[$j+1]['day_name'];
                    //timings
                    $data_set->special_timings_same_time = $data_set->special_days_nested_array[$j]['start_time'].' - '.$data_set->special_days_nested_array[$j]['end_time']; 

            }

            else{
                $data_set->special_time_different_time_array[$data_set->special_days_nested_array[$j+1]['day_name']]['day_name'] =  $data_set->special_days_nested_array[$j+1]['day_name'];
                $data_set->special_time_different_time_array[$data_set->special_days_nested_array[$j+1]['day_name']]['start_time'] = $data_set->special_days_nested_array[$j+1]['start_time'];
                $data_set->special_time_different_time_array[$data_set->special_days_nested_array[$j+1]['day_name']]['end_time'] = $data_set->special_days_nested_array[$j+1]['end_time'];
            }
            //$j++;


        }
```

How can I handle these two cases in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, but may be you need some grouping function.

```
$case1 = Array
        (
             Array
                (
                    'day_name' => 'Mon',
                    'start_time' => '01:00 pm',
                    'end_time' => '07:00 pm',
                ),
            Array
                (
                    'day_name' => 'Wed',
                    'start_time' => '01:00 pm',
                    'end_time' => '07:00 pm',
                ),
            Array
                (
                    'day_name' => 'Fri',
                    'start_time' => '01:00 pm',
                    'end_time' => '07:00 pm',
                ),
             Array
                (
                    'day_name' => 'Sun',
                    'start_time' => '01:00 pm',
                    'end_time' => '07:00 pm',
                ),
        );

$case2 = Array
        (
             Array
                (
                    'day_name' => 'Mon',
                    'start_time' => '01:00 pm',
                    'end_time' => '07:00 pm',
                ),
            Array
                (
                    'day_name' => 'Tue',
                    'start_time' => '12:00 am',
                    'end_time' => '09:00 pm',
                ),
            Array
                (
                    'day_name' => 'Wed',
                    'start_time' => '01:00 pm',
                    'end_time' => '07:00 pm',
                ),
        );
$case3 = Array
        (
             Array
                (
                    'day_name' => 'Mon',
                    'start_time' => '01:00 pm',
                    'end_time' => '07:00 pm',
                ),
            Array
                (
                    'day_name' => 'Tue',
                    'start_time' => '01:00 pm',
                    'end_time' => '07:00 pm',
                ),
            Array
                (
                    'day_name' => 'Wed',
                    'start_time' => '12:00 am',
                    'end_time' => '09:00 pm',
                ),
             Array
                (
                    'day_name' => 'Thu',
                    'start_time' => '12:00 am',
                    'end_time' => '09:00 pm',
                ),
        );


function group_same_interval($carry, $item)
{
    $interval = $item['start_time'].' - '.$item['end_time'];
    if (array_key_exists($interval, $carry))
    {
        $carry[$interval][] = $item['day_name'];
    }
    else
    {
        $carry[$interval] = array($item['day_name']);
    }

    return $carry;
}

print_r(array_reduce($case1, 'group_same_interval', array()));
print_r(array_reduce($case2, 'group_same_interval', array()));
print_r(array_reduce($case3, 'group_same_interval', array()));
```

The result looks as follows

```
Array
(
    [01:00 pm - 07:00 pm] => Array
        (
            [0] => Mon
            [1] => Wed
            [2] => Fri
            [3] => Sun
        )

)
Array
(
    [01:00 pm - 07:00 pm] => Array
        (
            [0] => Mon
            [1] => Wed
        )

    [12:00 am - 09:00 pm] => Array
        (
            [0] => Tue
        )

)
Array
(
    [01:00 pm - 07:00 pm] => Array
        (
            [0] => Mon
            [1] => Tue
        )

    [12:00 am - 09:00 pm] => Array
        (
            [0] => Wed
            [1] => Thu
        )

)
```